# jQuery Slick Slider filtering with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Here is a HTML for slick slider:

```
<div class="slick">
    <div class="black phone"></div>
    <div class="white phone"></div>
    <div class="green phone"></div>
    <div class="black ipad"></div>
    <div class="white ipad"></div>
    <div class="green ipad"></div>
    <div class="black tablet"></div>
    <div class="white tablet"></div>
    <div class="green tablet"></div>
</div>
```

I need to filter by color (black, white, green) and device (phone, ipad, tablet).
So for example, need to filter by classname of `.white` and `.tablet`.
Filter format is : "color" and "device". It's dynamic, not static.
Please advice me. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's impossible.
Slick slider don't support such filtering.

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution or workaround for this? I'm in the exact same boat.

Answer (score 6):

This is actually quite simple.

As slick just uses jquery's `.filter()` http://api.jquery.com/filter/ , you can use a multiple class selector in a single string. Just join the classes you want to keep with a comma.

```
     let slidesToKeep = ['.green.tablet', '.green.phone', '.ipad'].join(',');
     // slidesToKeep now equals '.green.tablet,.green.phone,.ipad'
     $('.slick').slick('slickFilter', slidesToKeep);
```

I've created a codepen demo, so you can add as many filters as you like: [Slick Carousel multiple filter demo](https://codepen.io/timrross/details/zRxGMe/).

**Edit for text links**

It is pretty straight forward to use text links rather than select boxes. you could just use a click listener on a text link.

Add text like this:

```
<span class="color-filter" data-value=".black">black</span>
<span class="color-filter" data-value=".white">white</span>
<span class="color-filter" data-value=".green">green</span>
```

The click listener:

```
$('form.filter span').on('click', function() {
    var filterClass = $(this).data('value')
    $('.slick').slick('slickUnfilter')
    $('.slick').slick('slickFilter', filterClass)
});
```

I forked the original code pen to show it working... https://codepen.io/timrross/pen/JxyVjE

Comment: Thank you for this, it is almost exactly what I am lookng for! One thing I am trying to do though is use links instead of a select field. So there would just be links for black, green and white and when clicked on it will change the slider. Is this possible at all?

Comment: I've updated my original answer with code to use text links instead.

Comment: Hi Tim, I know this is an old post but how can we reset the filter when ALL is selected from the drop down? At the moment nothing shows when this is selected. I need to keep the initial option value as empty (value="") and I am just looking for a way to reset the form options when this is selected.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to filter multiple conditions with slick slider. You need to filter all your conditions at one.

```
let slidesToKeep = ['.green.tablet', '.green.phone', '.ipad'];
$slickSlider.slick('slickFilter', String(slidesToKeep));
```