# slick slider filter by class issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, filter, slider

It's there any way I can filter the slide by class?
I fail to do so.
I need a multiple item per slide slider with a filter by class.
Or any other jquery plugin recommend to use?
link: http://jsfiddle.net/bre9427s/34/

I am really appreciate if somebody can help

```
<div class="slick-buttons">
  <a class="filter-btn view-all active">View All</a>
  <a class="filter-btn view-a">View a</a>
  <a class="filter-btn view-b">View b</a>
  <a class="filter-btn view-c">View c</a>
</div>

<section class="slider">
  <div class="category-a">slide1-a</div>
  <div class="category-b">slide2-b</div>
  <div class="category-c">slide3-c</div>
  <div class="category-a">slide4-a</div>
  <div class="category-c">slide5-c</div>
  <div class="category-b">slide6-b</div>
</section>

$(".slider").slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 500,
    settings: {
      dots: false,
      arrows: false,
      infinite: false,
      slidesToShow: 2,
      slidesToScroll: 2
    }
  }]
});

var filtered = false;

$('.viewall').on('click', function() {
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $('.viewall').addClass('active');
  $('.slider').slick('slickUnfilter');
  filtered = false;
});
$('.view-a').on('click', function() {
  $('.slider').slick('slickFilter','.category-a');
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $('.view-a').addClass('active');
  filtered = true;
});

$('.view-b').on('click', function() {
  $('.slider').slick('slickFilter','.category-b');
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $('.view-b').addClass('active');
  filtered = true;
});

$('.view-c').on('click', function() {
  $('.slider').slick('slickFilter','.category-c');
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $('.view-c').addClass('active');
  filtered = true;
});
```

Comment: "TT" is a crying face with tears

Comment: Your first problem is that `slickFilter` has to be passed a slide or slides, whereas you are passing it the class of a div *within* a slide. Instead of doing `$('.slider').slick('slickFilter','.category-a');` you could do `$('.slider').slick('slickFilter',$('.category-a').parent().parent());`.

Answer (score 6):

Omid's code will work with some tweaks and requirements.
If you build it on top of the original fiddle, be sure to update the code to reference a specific version of slick, like https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js  The default master version in the original fiddle does not work.  Also change Omid's .employees references to be .slider.  Here is a working version of Omid's code:
http://jsfiddle.net/bre9427s/21

Another very good answer to this questions exists with a demo on this question:
[jQuery Slick Slider filtering with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41104225/jquery-slick-slider-filtering-with-multiple-conditions/48519591#48519591)

Tim also shows how to properly use the slickFilter and slickUnfilter commands with multiple class names separated by commas.  However the basic use of slickFilter remains the same:

```
  $('form.filter span').on('click', function() {
    var filterClass = $(this).data('value');
    $('.filter-class').text(filterClass);
    $('.slick').slick('slickUnfilter');
    $('.slick').slick('slickFilter', filterClass);
  });
```

The code pen showing his work with links is here:
https://codepen.io/timrross/pen/JxyVjE

You could also do it with dropdowns as shown here:
https://codepen.io/timrross/pen/zRxGMe

**WARNING:** There is a functional difference between the .min.js and the non-minified .js version. There are a number of situations where the **non-minified does NOT work** and where **the minified version DOES work**.  This has been confirmed by multiple people in other threads.  Sorry, I don't have the links at the moment, but you can easily confirm it using my examples above, removing the .min from the slick required file url.  I thought I was going nuts at first.

I did some side-by-side comparison and even brought some of the minified code (with some cleanup) into the original JS file, but I was not able to find where the problem code is. It's not in the SlickFilter functions, so far as I can tell. So I think it must be in some  lower level routine/structure in the class. Business needs meant I no longer had time to diagnose. So, long story short, if your filtering code doesn't work at all but it should: try switching to the minimized version and you may suddenly find your filters and code now work fine.

Comment: This answer needs more exposure! The difference between min and non-min is hidden and unexpected. I was using the non-minified fork that fixes the passive listener warning in Chrome, but as stated, the filter function is broken unless you're using the minified original!

Comment: Wow this was 100% it! I was losing my mind because the slick filter function was not working (it just kept nuking the entire container), turns out my project was compiling it's *own* slick.min.js (via a compilerconfig.json) which was somehow materially different from the original slick.min.js! Once I switched it, it magically worked.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

html:

```
<div class="slick-buttons">
   <a class="filter-btn active" data-attribute="all">View All</a>
   <a class="filter-btn" data-attribute="a">View a</a>
   <a class="filter-btn" data-attribute="b">View b</a>
   <a class="filter-btn" data-attribute="c">View c</a>
</div>

<section class="slider">
   <div class="a">slide1-a</div>
   <div class="b">slide2-b</div>
   <div class="c">slide3-c</div>
   <div class="a">slide4-a</div>
   <div class="c">slide5-c</div>
   <div class="b">slide6-b</div>
</section>
```

js:

```
$(".slider").slick({
   slidesToShow: 3,
   responsive: [{
     breakpoint: 500,
    settings: {
      dots: false,
      arrows: false,
      infinite: false,
      slidesToShow: 2,
      slidesToScroll: 2
    }
  }]
});

var filtered = false;
$('.filter-btn').on('click',function(){
    $('.filter-btn').removeClass('active');
    var filter = $(this).data('attribute');
    if(filter=='all'){
        $('.employees').slick('slickUnfilter');
    }else{
        $('.employees').slick('slickUnfilter').slick('slickFilter','.'+filter);
    }
    $(this).addClass('active');
    filtered = true;
});
```

Comment: Is $('.employees') correct code based on your html provided?